# Help solving the inequality $2^n \leq (n+1)!$, n is integer

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponentiation, factorial

I need help solving the following inequality I encountered in the middle of a proof in my calculus I textbook:

$2^n \leq (n+1)!$

Where **$\mathbf{n}$ in an integer**.

I've tried applying lg to both members, but got stuck at:

$n \leq \lg(n+1) + \lg(n) + \lg(n-1) + ... + \lg(3) + 1$

A proof by induction is acceptable, but I wanted an algebraic one. I find it more... elegant?

Comment: $2^n = \overbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdots 2}^{n}$ and $(n+1)! = \overbrace{2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdots (n+1)}^{n}$. See it yet?

Comment: Oh, my goodness, I feel terribly inappropriate.

Comment: We've all been there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(n+1)!=2\cdot 3\cdot \dots\cdot(n+1)$ here a product of $n$ numbers all are at least 2 so the result follows...

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

$$\frac{(n+1)!}{2^n}=\frac{2}{2}\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{2}\cdots \frac{n-1}{2}\frac{n}{2}\frac{n+1}{2}$$